# Run Octave remotely and display locally via X11

Tags: ssh, x11, octave

I'm currently implementing some machine learning algorithm by octave and run in the remote server. Once I type some drawing commands such like hist() it shows that

```
warning: X11 DISPLAY environment variable not set
```

Is it possible that I set the environment as my local X11 service. How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the remote server by ssh and add the option -X

```
ssh -X remote_server
```

Then ssh will enable X11 forwarding.