# How to plot from octave to a pdf without X11

Tags: pdf, plot, png, x11, octave

I want to create pdf or png plots from octave on an ubuntu system where I just have a command line, no X11, no windows. I want to do something like this:

```
plot(x, y);
print -dpng myplot.png
```

But plot gives me this warning:

```
warning: X11 DISPLAY environment variable not set
```

And both commands just give me a character graphic rendition on the console. Do I need to set GNUTERM to something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really old question but it was the top result for me. Relevant for today's cloud services, here are ways to approach the problem:

```
figure ("visible", "off")
plot (1:10)
print output.png
```

If you don't want to work just with files, X11 can be forwarded for remote viewing. [Run Octave remotely and display locally via x11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337234/run-octave-remotely-and-display-locally-via-x11) assumes the X11 libraries are installed and ready to go...so just add -X to ssh:

```
ssh -X remoteserver
```

To get X11 there in the first place, these articles:

- [X11 forwarding from amazon ec2 ami](https://superuser.com/questions/249045/x11-forwarding-from-amazon-ec2-ami)
- [AWS Developer Forums: X11 forwarding...DISPLAY not set...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162871)

suggest:

- Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set

  - X11Forwarding yes
  - CentOS might need these instead:

    - ForwardX11 yes
    - ForwardX11Trusted yes
- $ sudo yum groupinstall "X Window System"

  - or install the single packages you want
- $ export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0

  - This variable is only missing if xauth isn't installed
- $ sudo yum install xauth

  - Not installed by default

and just in case you indeed run into a GNUTERM error:
[Octave Plotting Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166595/octave-plotting-error) suggests compiling gnuplot with X11 support and setting the environment before plotting anything:

```
$ (whatever installs) gnuplot --with-x11

Then in Octave:
#setenv("GNUTERM", "qt")
setenv("GNUTERM","X11")
plot(x,y)
```